# Dúvida utilizando wizard bullet type

Tags: genexus

Ex. Estou armazenando no banco qualquer coisa, mas quero pegar o Id que foi armazenado e passar este valor para o próximo passo.

Não consigo imaginar uma forma de pegar o Id do passo anterior e passar para o passo seguinte, é possível fazer isso?

Obg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde. O id é Autonumber? Você está trabalhando com Business Component? Se assim, logo de fazer o Save já vai poder pegar o Id do registro e depois do Save pode fazer o commit no banco. Vai ter que fazer o Save e logo o Commit, por isso o melhor vai ser fazer isso tudo junto no passo final.

Passo a passo vai poder ter toda a informação sempre salvada na variavel &WizardData. Nossa sugestão é guardar em cada passo toda a informação e no passo final fazer o Save e commit no banco.

Qualquer dúvida nos pode escrever a nosso e-mail de suporte: support@workwithplus.com ou falamos pelo Skype (supportwwp)